# Regex Python conditional parsing of nested tags

Tags: python, html, regex, nested, conditional-statements

I'm trying to scrape an HTML page using Python, and I have problems in retrieving table rows. They can be either 'simple', so that a `<tr>` tag will only contain `<th>` and `<td>` tags, but they can also contain a further nested `<table>` with another set of `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` tags.

Thus, it can be:

```
<tr>
  <th>...</th>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

or:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

The idea was to extract with a regex row after row of the table as shown in the two previous code boxes. But the pattern `'(<tr>[\s\S]*?(<table)?[\s\S]*?(?(2)(</table>))[\s\S]*?</tr>)'` will still fit a shortened string, ending at the first `</tr>` encountered, the one still being within the nested `<table>`. Has anyone a clever idea how to solve this, and forcing to first search for a `</table>` once a `<table>` has been found before 'accepting' a `</td>`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ use beautifulsoup or some other parser

Comment: Regex is a **regular** language and shouldn't be used for purposes like this.

Comment: Maybe look into the BeautifulSoup module (`bs4`), it's a great html parser.

Comment: Ok guys, many thanks, you convinced me! I'll have a look at the beautifulsoup thing :)